# give me a same code for deleting purposes..vb.net 2010 - closed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The code below is my code for saving records

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        'Change the following to your access database location
        dataFile = "C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "insert into tblODR ([ID], [Office], [Elements], [Objectives], [Initiatves]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("ID", CType(IDTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Office", CType(OfficeTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Elements", CType(ElementsTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Objectives", CType(ObjectivesTextBox.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Initiatves", CType(InitiatvesTextBox.Text, String)))

        Try

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            Me.Validate()
            Me.TblODRBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TblODRTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet.tblODR)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

can anyone give me a same code BUT, for deleting purposes.. the code above adds a new record and shows instantly in the datagridview after adding it..(before i have code for adding purposes but it wont add instantly in the datagridview)..
What i want is, a code that when i delete a record using a textbox (i'm deleting records by inputting the ID Number of a record in a textbox)..the deleted record will show instantly after deleting it.. (my code as of now, when i delete a record, it would delete the record BUT i have to close the form and run the program again to show if the deleted record have been deleted)

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: @Mahadev what do you mean by show you my efforts? i dont get it.. should i show the system?

Comment: Nope. What did you tried to delete the records ? Code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Deleting Records on DataGridView) - VB.NET 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612111/deleting-records-on-datagridview-vb-net-2010)

Comment: Please do not repost the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612111/deleting-records-on-datagridview-vb-net-2010) just hours later

Comment: @Plutonix read it please,, both title are different..they have same code BUT they dont have the same answer i'm seeking :3
the problem "Deleting Records on DataGridView", the answer i'm seeking there is that when i tried to delete records , the deleted records wont even be removed at the datagridview..
WHILE this problem "give me a same code for deleting purposes..vb.net 2010".. what im seeking here is a code for deleting purposes, like the code above(the above code is for saving purposes and its working)

Answer (score 1):

You can use gridview1.refresh() method to refresh your grid on the delete button , so when delete common executes, it will refresh your gridview to update the new record use gridview1.update() to update the  changes that you have made. Or you can also make your own method to refresh your gridview,here is the sample method to refresh the grid like this

```
Public Sub Gridrefresh(ByVal s As String, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from  " + s + "", con.dbconnection())
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

here s represent name of your table , when you call this method  u can use like this Gridrefresh("name of table ",datagridView1 name ), Hope this will help you

Comment: your Welcome , and i am glad that my code help you to solve your problem , ! Cheers